# How to properly initialize an array so that threads do not exceed it (example of a matrix)?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, executorservice

I am trying to understand how forwarding threads to certain processes / tasks works.

I want to create matrix:

- matrix multiplication (A * B = C)
- passing the indicated number of threads for execution (for example, I
  want this execution of the matrix to perform ONLY 6 threads)

I created a thread pool for this (ExecutorService) - but I have a problem with the correct initialization of it - when I try to run the code, I receive an error that the threads exceed the initialized array

So how can I solve this so that the threads are passed correctly without exceeding the table?

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

class MatrixMultiplication2 {

    //initializes variables for dimensions
    public static int M = 3;
    public static int N = 3;

    //Declares Arrays A,B,C, and an Array or WorkerThreads
    public static int [][] A = {{1,4}, {2,5}, {3,6}}; //Initializes A
    public static int [][] B = {{8,7,6}, {5,4,3}};    //Initializes B
    public static int [][] C = new int [M][N];
    public static WorkerThread [][] Threads = new WorkerThread[3][3];


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
    
        int numberOfThreads = 1;
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
            Runnable worker = new Thread(new WorkerThread(M,N,A,B,C));
            executor.execute(worker);
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        }

       
        System.out.println("Elements of Matrix C:");
        for (int i = 0; i<M; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<N; j++){
                System.out.println("["+i+","+j+"] = "+C[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

part 2

```
 class WorkerThread extends Thread{
        private int row;
        private int col;
        private int [][] A;
        private int [][] B;
        private int [][] C;
    
        public WorkerThread(int row, int col, int[][] A,
                            int[][] B, int[][] C) {
            this.row = row;
            this.col = col;
            this.A = A;
            this.B = B;
            this.C = C;
        }
    
        public void run() {
            C[row][col] = (A[row][0] * B[0][col])+ (A[row][1]*B[1][col]) ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You set `row` and `col` in the `WorkerThread` to the dimensions of the result matrix which exceeds the bounds of at least the matrix `C`

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few problems here:

1. An `ExecutorPool` manages its own threads, you should not be making your own. Your code compiles  because your thread is **also** a `Runnable`, and that's all that executorpool wants. Change `WorkerThread` to read: `class WorkerJob implements Runnable`, and `Thread[] threads` to `WorkerJob[][] jobs` (or if you prefer, `Runnable[][] jobs`, it makes no difference). In fact, you don't use that `threads` thing at all, you don't ever stuff any values in there. Get rid of the field entirely, it serves no purpose.
2. Don't use isTerminated like this.

   ```
   while (!executor.isTerminated()) {}
   ```

   this is a *busy loop* - your laptop / PC's fans will spike, your power draw will go way up, and crucially those jobs that need to be finished are slowed waaaaay down. Don't do this. There's an `awaitTermination` method **right there** in the API, just that instead. Replace that while loop with `executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.DAYS)`.
3. I hope you're aware that the overhead of setting up an executor pool and running things in threads is a few **million times** more expensive than that calculation. Just setting up a basic for loop and turning all this code into 3 lines worth, setting `C[row][col]` in a for loop, would be a few thousand times faster.
4. You've confused yourself - all this threading business, whilst rather badly written, isn't the cause of your error. Keep it simple - just test your basic code first before doing all this. Look past the stuff you don't quite understand and focus on the stuff you do, make sure those bits are at least correct.

   You create a new `WorkerThread` object, passing `M` and `N` for `row` and `col`. These are always `3`. Java is 0-indexed, so this: `int[] x = new int[3]; x[3] = 0;` will cause an error (`x[3]` is the 4th element, and the array only has 3). It looks like this is simply a bug and you meant to make a for loop there that loops `i` from 0 to M and `j` from 0 to N, making 1 WorkerThread object with each unique combination.

Learn to walk before you learn to run.

Comment: Thanks for such an extensive explanation, I have corrected most of the things, but I still have a problem with point 4 - as you say when the 3rd element is exceeded, the 4th will throw an error, how can I correct it so that the value of the given elements automatically adjusts to the size?

Comment: Just look at your code, forget about the threading stuff. You're running `x[3] = foo` on an array that was initialized as `new int[3]`. If you don't understand why that is the cause of the problem (or how you end up doing that - by passing M and N and treating them as the row / col idx), maybe take a walk, and start back at the 'beginning with java' tutorial.